# When the value of i++ operation taking place and store in its reference in Java ..?

Tags: java

I am reading Thinking in java book, which is quite interesting, there is an example in the book, and the behavior of the example and the output is not as I  expected.

The Example:

```
package net.mindview.util;

import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

class Shared {
    private int refcount = 0;
    private static long counter = 0;
    private final long id = counter++;

    public Shared() {
        print("Creating " + this);
    }

    public void addRef() {
        refcount++;
    }

    protected void dispose() {
        if (--refcount == 0)
            print("Disposing " + this);
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(id);
        return "Shared " + id;
    }
}

class Composing {
    private Shared shared;
    private static long counter = 0;
    private final long id = counter++;

    public Composing(Shared shared) {
        print("Creating " + this);
        this.shared = shared;
        this.shared.addRef();
    }

    protected void dispose() {
        print("disposing " + this);
        shared.dispose();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Composing " + id;
    }
}

public class ReferenceCounting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared shared = new Shared();
        Composing[] composing = { new Composing(shared), new Composing(shared),
                new Composing(shared), new Composing(shared),
                new Composing(shared) };
        for (Composing c : composing)
            c.dispose();
    }
}
```

This is an example of dispose method, which I fully understand, my question is in the value of id in Shared class.

As I am learning from Thinking in java, the initialization of the field and objects should occur before any method get called, even the Constructor, But the output for the constructor of Shared class is "Creating Shared 0" which the value of id is considered to be 0 in spite of `private final long id = counter++;` has took a place and now as I imagine the id value should be 1 not zero. Could any one explain to me the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`counter++` is post-increment, this means the value is assigned **before** incrementation. pre-increment on the other side would show the behavior you expected.

Comment: Thanks alot that explains too much .. I got it now ... but was my idea about initialization correct?

Comment: @WaseemSwaileh do you mean that thing about intializing fields, it's more secure to initialize fields first, though that's mostly a question of coding-style.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of post-increment. In other words, the old value is stored in a temporary variable and returned after incrementing. It is the equivalent of:

```
int i = 0;
int tmp = i;
i += 1;
System.out.println(tmp);   //prints 0
```

The opposite is pre-increment, where the incremented value is returned:

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(++i);  //prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `counter++` it is a **post-increment** operator (on the next line, counter is increased by one). Based on your question, I think you expected the behavior of the **pre-increment** operator. Change

```
final long id = counter++;
```

to something like

```
final long id = ++counter;
```

or even

```
final long id = counter + 1;
counter++;
```